# Find entities from list of entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0

I have a list of entities like below.

```
Entity1 { Id=1, From=01/01/2011, To=31/01/2011, Status=true }
Entity2 { Id=1, From=01/02/2011, To=28/02/2011, Status=false}
Entity2 { Id=2, From=01/02/2011, To=28/02/2011, Status=false}
Entity3 { Id=3, From=01/01/2011, To=31/01/2011, Status=true }
Entity4 { Id=4, From=01/01/2011, To=31/01/2011, Status=true }
Entity5 { Id=1, From=01/03/2011, To=31/03/2011, Status=false}
Entity6 { Id=4, From=31/03/2011, To=10/04/2011, Status=false}
```

I want to find the entities which have the oldest from date and latest last date. ( entities covering whole from date and to date)

**Basically I need to get the entities which have distinct from and to dates. Also the starting entity should have the oldest From date and final entity should have the latest To date**

In this case the expected result is entities starting from ***01/01/2011*** to ***10/04/2011***.

**Update**

```
Entity 1 has the oldest from date : 01/01/2011
Entiry 2 which falls under : 01/01/2011 and 10/04/2011
Entity 3 which falls under 01/01/2011 and 10/04/2011(but entity 1 has same from and to date as Entity3 so entity 3 not a valid)
Entity 4 which falls under 01/01/2011 and 10/04/2011(but entity 1 has same from and to date as Entity4 so entity 4 not a valid)
Entity 5 which falls under : 01/01/2011 and 10/04/2011
Entity 6 has the most recent To date : 10/04/2011
So Valid entries are Entity1, Entity2, Entity5, Entity6
```

I tried something like this

```
var dates = (EntityList.GroupBy(offer => offer.id)
             .Select(group =>
                 new { offerid = group.Key,
                       offers = group.OrderBy(o => o.From)
                       })
             .OrderBy(g => g.offers.First().From) 
        . FirstOrDefault
 ().offers.First();
```

But I think it should do without grouping, but I am not quite sure

Any help is appreciate

Thanks

Comment: I'm having a little trouble parsing your criteria, there seems to be no discrimination in your code.

Comment: Basically I need to get the entities which have `distinct` from and to dates. Also the starting entity should have the oldest from date and final entity should have the latest end date

Comment: What is "end date" and what is "last date"?  Your entities don't seem to have these properties.  Is that the same as the To Date?  Please be consistent in your terminology.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: yes, its **todate**

Comment: @huMptyduMpty could you explain why end date `31/03/2011` is expected, and why entities `Entity1, Entity2, Entity6` satisfy that date? Also you have several entities with same name and also some entities have equal id's in your data (i.e. there is two different entites `Entity2`)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty data is still same - two `Entity2` entries, and three objects with `id = 1`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: I have updated the question in detail. Please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dates = from e in EntityList
            orderby e.Id
            group e by new { e.From, e.To } into g
            select g.First();
```

Query will return only first (ordered by id) entities from groups with same from-to dates.

Comment: This will duplicate the entities with similar from and to dates?

Comment: You want to get dates only, or first of entities, ordered by some condition?

Comment: Sure it is. Please specify conditions of selection

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use something like this:

```
var selectedEntity = EntityList.OrderBy(e => e.From)
                               .ThenByDescending(e => e.To)
                               .FirstOrDefault();
```

UPDATE:

Could you use the Distinct method?

```
var selectedEntity = EntityList.OrderBy(e => e.From)
                               .ThenByDescending(e => e.To)
                               .Distinct();
```

Comment: This will return duplicate entities which have same from and to dates